# mrmr feature selection and SVM classifier what is mean of m?

Tags: matlab, svm, feature-selection

I'm trying to do mrmr feature selection and SVM classifier.I get discreet nci data set from [penglab web site](http://penglab.janelia.org/proj/mRMR/).

```
nci=importdata('test_nci9_s3.csv');
ncid=nci.data(:,1);
ncif=nci.data(:,2:9713);
[feanciq] = mrmr_miq_d(ncif, ncid, 60);
[feancid] = mrmr_mid_d(ncif, ncid, 60);
 for i=1:10,
    for j=1:60,
        testnciq(i,j)=ncif(i,feanciq(j));
    end;
 end;
 for i=11:60,
    for j=1:60,
        trainnciq(i-10,j)=ncif(i,feanciq(j));
    end;
 end; 
 for i=1:10,
    for j=1:3,
        testncid(i,j)=ncif(i,feancid(j));
    end;
 end;
 for i=11:60,
    for j=1:3,
        trainncid(i-10,j)=ncif(i,feancid(j));
    end;
 end;
 SVMStructq=fitcecoc(trainnciq,ncid(11:60));
 SVMStructd=fitcecoc(trainncid,ncid(11:60));
 td=predict(SVMStructd,trainncid(2,:));
 tq=predict(SVMStructq,trainnciq(2,:));
 disp(tq);
 disp(td);
```

[table](http://penglab.janelia.org/papersall/docpdf/2004_JBCB_feasel-04-06-15.pdf)

What is mean of m(m=3,6,9....48,54,60) table at page 194 in upper paper?
How get i these MID and MIQ variables like table?